# How to save URI from HTTP request in Javascript (Google Drive API)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm desperately trying to follow this: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#save-session-uri

I've been able to use javascript to upload a file to my Google Drive, however I'm now trying to upload large files (>1GB) which crashes the browser in my current scripts. So my new script uses the resumeable upload option. I've sent the Resumable session initiation request and received back a 200 OK header with Location header URI.

The tutorial then says "Copy and save the session URI so you can use it for subsequent requests.". I cannot for the life of me work out how to do this in javascript? How do I save a URI from a header? Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm more used to python (in which I've managed to get resume-able upload working) but we need this done in javascript sadly. 
My code (obviously removed my client ID):

```
  // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
  // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
  var CLIENT_ID = '<YOURCLIENTID>';

  var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'];

  /**
   * Check if current user has authorized this application.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  /**
   * Handle response from authorization server.
   * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadDriveApi();
    } else {
      // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
      // clicking authorize button.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
   * @param {Event} event Button click event.
   */
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Load Drive API client library.
   * Use last parameter (empty function) to do something on load!
   */
  function loadDriveApi() {
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function(){});
  }



  function createFile(fileData) {
    var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    alert(fileData.name + " " + contentType);

    // Metadata
    var metadata = {
      'name' : fileData.name,
      'mimeType': contentType,
      'parents': [{'id':'0B1c3-viP2d_8QWMyenczTzdzSkk'}]
    };


    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path' : 'upload/drive/v3/files',
        'method' : 'POST',
        'params' : {'uploadType':'resumable'},
        'headers' : {
          'X-Upload-Content-Type' : contentType,
          'X-Upload-Content-Length' : 1024*256
        },
        'body' : metadata
    });

    request.execute();
  }

  /**
   * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message as its text node.
   * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
   */
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('output');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }


  //files is a filelist
  function fileselected(files) 
  {
      for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) // for file in list of files
      {
          var f = files[i]; // Pick the current file (i) from the file list
          appendPre("Uploading " + f.name);
          createFile(f);
          appendPre(f.name + " upload complete"); // Upload the current file
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the OP originally said in an edit to the question, you need to use the callback of `request.execute()` like so:

```
request.execute(function(resp, raw_resp) {
    appendPre(raw_resp);
    // GETS THE LOCATION! WOO
    appendPre(JSON.parse(raw_resp).gapiRequest.data.headers.location);
});
```